# Specific browser support list for Selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium

On Selenium's site, they say about Firefox support:

> Support for Firefox is the latest release, the previous release, the latest ESR release and the previous ESR release.
>
> For example Selenium 2.40.0 (released on Feb 19, 2014) supports Firefox 27, 26, 24, 17

But the current stable release is not 2.40.0, it's 2.47.1. Is there a specific, line by line rundown of Selenium versions along with references to specific browser versions?

Comment: What it says is correct... you are looking at an example.